# ckeditor field shows html tags in content only when value not changed

Tags: ember.js

I am supporting an ember site that was build by someone else. The frontend is Emberjs with a Drupal 7 backend.

The site has a user profile where they can enter a bio. The initial bio entry is fine, but if the user edits the profile (changes some other field for example) but does not change the bio text, then it saves something like `<p>My bio</p>`as the value of the field where the html tags are saved as text.

The component.js for the form has this in it:

```
bodyChanged(newValue) {
  this.get('profile').set('bio', newValue);
},
```

Suspecting this is the culprit but not sure what to do to fix.

Thanks

Comment: include the component.hbs code too

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. My deserializing function that sucks in the drupal json was using `json[fieldName]['und'][0]['safe_value'];` as the value. When I switched it to use the `json[fieldName]['und'][0]['value'];` the problem went away.